# checkSound() Function and Express interfering

Tags: javascript, express

I currently have a function set up in my global.js file that starts a song and pauses it if the 4 key is pressed.  However, when I implement this function it causes my routing to stop working.  So in my mainMenu.js file when you press the 1 key it should bring you to game.html but nothing happens.  I'm not sure of what is causing this interference.  Any ideas as to how I can stop this from happening

global.js:

```
window.onload = function(){
}

//music
var audio = new Audio('/music/oregonMusic.mp3')

function checkSound(){
    audio.play();

    document.onkeypress = function(e){
        if(audio.paused){
            audio.play();
        }
        else if(!audio.paused && e.keyCode === 52){
            audio.pause();
        }
    }
}
checkSound();
```

mainMenu.js:

```
window.onload = function(){
    //console.log('swing');
    checkSound();
}

document.onkeypress = function(e){
    //console.log('key pressed: ' + e.keyCode) 

    if(e.keyCode === 49){
        window.location = 'game'
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === 51){
        window.location = "topTen"
    }
}
```

Comment: there can only be one `document.onkeypress = fn` ... use `document.addEventListener('keypress', fn);` instead

Comment: @JaromandaX can you give me an example of how I would write that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) { ... }; // 1
document.onkeypress = function(e) { ... }; // 2
```

results in only function `// 2` being called on keypress

instead, you should use addEventListener

so, `global.js`

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if(audio.paused){
        audio.play();
    }
    else if(!audio.paused && e.keyCode === 52){
        audio.pause();
    }
});
```

and `mainMenu.js`

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 49){
        window.location = 'game'
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === 51){
        window.location = "topTen"
    }
});
```

now both handlers will be called

Comment: so I can just put my if statements into the function of the eventlistener correct?

Comment: the code in the body of the event handler functions would be unchanged,